# DRF - extend obtain auth token

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have Django Rest Framework with token auth. I have a following url `url(r'^api/auth/', views.obtain_auth_token),` which returns me token.

What I need to do is perform some db logic, when user performs authorization which is getting the token. I need to query db and do some stuff there.

It seems to me that I have somehow to override default behaviour and add some custom logic to `obtain_auth_token`.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ObtainAuthToken from Rest Framework gets or creates a token for an specific user and then sends it in the Response, all of these behaviour is done in the post method.

The documentation says:

> If you need a customized version of the obtain_auth_token view, you can do so by overriding the ObtainAuthToken view class, and using that in your url conf instead.

So you can override the post method, or even create your own APIView to create the Token and add the behaviour you want. In order to do that, change your url:

```
url(r'^api/auth/', views.custom_obtain_token)
```

And in views.py:

```
class CustomObtainToken(APIView):
    ...
    def post(self, request):
        <your logic>
        <get token n your own way or using DRF way>
        return Response({'token': token})
custom_obtain_token = CustomObtainToken.as_view()
```

Comment: Sorry, can you please clarify, how to create token DRF way ?

Comment: After validating the serializer and verifying the user exists or is authenticated, you can do `token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)`. This is the way DRF do it. `Token` is a model and you can import it from `rest_framework.authtoken.models`

Comment: How can I validate serializer and verify that the user exists ? Make a queryset to user model and chech if username .exists() ?

Comment: Give it a look at the way DRF handles it: [AuthToken-view](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/authtoken/views.py)